# Map style identification

Tags: 3d, skeleton

We are looking for a visualization solution to track a device to locate its floor and room in 3D（especially the skeleton and the room of the building.

Now we do have the OSGB data for the whole building, and deployed them as b3dm. However there are two problems:

1. The target will be blocked by the wall(the texture)
2. The rooms of each floor can not be displayed too.

So We need a 3D building keeping only the skeleton. We do not know the exact name of this map type. The following screenshots are close to what we want.

[Image1](https://pic.vjshi.com/2019-12-18/23b189f8399888496881000424ffa7e6/online/89645f03b9667459375ee927d96a8ff9.jpg?x-oss-process=style/resize_w_720) [Image2](https://i.imgur.com/HJAvPtF.png)

Also we should be able to track the target in any view which will scale, rotate, move the map, so a static image is not enough.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a map, a 3D image maybe. What is OGSB data?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. I updated that.

Comment: Ah, some kind of 3D data. The answer to your last question would then be Yes.

Comment: Now we do have the osgb data for the whole building, and deployed them as `b3dm`. However there are two problems: 1 The target will be blocked by the wall(the texture) 2 The rooms of each floor can not be displayed too.

Comment: You could ask a separate question about that

Comment: IMO, they belong to one question. We need a 3d building keeping only the skeleton which we do not know exact the name of this map type.

Comment: Are you looking for the word "wireframe"? That's the usual term for displaying only the outline of 3d models.

Comment: Then you should stick to 'What is the name of this map'. Don't add noise about *how* to generate such a map

Comment: @Berend I remove the  `how to generate...` .  @Spacedman: Seems like the `wireframe` is  closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are "wireframe" renderings of the 3d model.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-frame_model

They are often used instead of solid modelling because they are quick to produce, so if you are doing animation you can check the movement without having to spend processor time rendering shaded surfaces etc.

Comment: Don't add followup questions in comments. Make a new question. You should also specify the software you have.